# Samsung S7 edge does not get FCM token in android version 7.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, samsung-mobile

`String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();`

Refreshed Token value is `null`.

My library version:

`com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2`

Comment: Is it working on other devices?

Comment: yes it's working fine on other device.

Comment: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2 try with latest version

Comment: you can paste your error here..

Comment: yes it's working updating version to 11.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This issue is resolve updating version of the library.
Make sure you have to use the same version of your google play service library and firebase messaging library.

My old library:
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2

Replace with latest version:
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
```